# Cálculo coseno, valores mayores a treinta se vuelven inexactos

Tags: python, poo

```
class CalculadoraTrigonometria:
    def __init__(self, ang):
        """ Funcion constructora """
        self.angulo = ang    
    def calcularCoseno(self):
        return self.operar(self.angulo, self.coseno)
    def operar(self, angulo, op):
        """ Esta es la funcion de orden superior """
        return op(angulo, 1, 1, -1)
    def coseno(self, x, x_2,  counter, signo):
        """ Funcion recursiva 
        A partir del numero 30 en adelante, los resultados
        son imprecisos y esto es debido a que los numeros que 
        se manejan despues de cierta llamada recursiva son demasiados
        altos para ser manejados en la memoria
        """
        try:
            # Si ocurre un error debido a que los numeros con los que se operan son
            # demasiado largos entonces termina la funcion y retorna x_2 como esta
            # hasta ahora
            x_2 = x_2 + signo*((x**(2*counter))/(self.factorial(2*counter)))
        except:
            return x_2
        x_2 = self.coseno(x,  x_2, counter + 1, (-1)*signo)
        return x_2
    def factorial(self, val):
        num = float(1)
        for i in range(1, val+1):
            num = float(num * i)
        return num
angulo    = float()
while True:
    try:
        angulo    = float(input("[!] Introduzca el angulo: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("[!] Valor invalido introducido")
        continue
    break
calc = CalculadoraTrigonometria(angulo)
print(f"[!] El coseno de {angulo} es: {calc.calcularCoseno()}")
```

A partir del numero `30` en adelante, los resultados son imprecisos y esto es debido a que los numeros que se manejan despues de cierta llamada recursiva son demasiados altos para ser manejados en la memoria. Si ocurre un error debido a que los numeros con los que se operan son demasiado largos entonces termina la funcion y retorna `x_2` como esta hasta ahora

Comment: Tu pregunta anterior (ahora eliminada) había sido cerrada. ¿En qué se diferencia esta pregunta de la anterior?

Comment: Ahora esta nucho mas compacto que el anterior

Answer (score 0):

Lo que intentas hacer es un programa que calcule una función trigonométrica, coseno en este caso, por el método de [Series de Taylor](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serie_de_Taylor).

```
sen(x) = x - (x^3)/3! + (x^5)/5! - (x^7)/7! + ...
cos(x) = 1 - (x^2)/2! + (x^4)/4! - (x^6)/6! + ...
```

Hay múltiples errores en el código original, entre ellos: en una serie polinomial, los ángulos van en [radianes](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radi%C3%A1n). Por otro lado un [factorial](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) NO puede ser de tipo `float()`. Adicional, el código que proporcionas está muy enredado, dificulta la visibilidad y la comprensión del mismo. Finalmente, el programador **tiene** que controlar sus errores, no delegárselos a un bloque `try/except`.

Resolviendo lo anterior, se puede escribir una clase mucho más sencilla para calcular la función. No incluyo la parte de `angulo = float(input("..."))`, etc, eso puede quedar igual:

```py
import math
# math solo se usa para traer math.pi = 3.1415... pero también se puede definir

class CalculadoraTrigonometria:
    def __init__(self, ang):
        """ Funcion constructora """
        self.angulo = ang * math.pi / 180 # <-- grados a radianes
    
    def calcularCoseno(self, iterations=10):
        cos = 0.0
        i = 0
        while i < iterations:
            sign = -1 if i%2 else 1
            cos += sign * (self.angulo**(2*i)) / self.factorial(2*i)
            i += 1
        return cos
    
    def factorial(self, val):
        num = 1
        for i in range(1, val+1):
            num *= i
        return num
```

Le agregué al método `calcularCoseno()` un argumento llamado `iterations` que representa la cantidad de iteraciones. Con 10 iteraciones la precisión es superior a 12 decimales, suficiente para cualquier cálculo *normal*.

Prueba

```py
>>> calc = CalculadoraTrigonometria(30)
>>> calc.calcularCoseno()
0.8660254037844386 # Comparando con la calculadora: 0.866025403784
>>> calc.calcularCoseno(4) # Con 4 iteraciones
0.8660252641005711 # Con 4 iteraciones la precisión es bastante buena
```